# OpenGL ES 2.0 lighting not working in iOS app

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently learning OpenGL 2.0 and Im creating a basic iPhone app. I have created a model in blender and have exported it to a .obj file and have written a parser that pulls in the co-ordinates. The shape displays fine but with no colour (its black). This implies that there is something wrong with the normals. But I have check the normals and ant find anything wrong with them. Is there something missing from my code?

I would be ever so grateful for any help with this!

Screen shot

[image]

here is my OpenGL code

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfVerticies * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, arrayOfVerticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_normalArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_normalArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GLKVertexAttribNormal, loader.currentCountOfNormals  * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3,loader.arrayOfNormals , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_textureArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_textureArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_textureBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfTextureCoordinates * sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, loader.arrayOftextureCoOrdinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));


glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

And My `DrawRect` Method

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray); 

    glUseProgram(_program);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

    #ifdef DEBUG_VERTEX_DATA_LOOP
    NSLog(@"size of c array * type %ld", loader.currentCountOfVerticies *sizeof(GLfloat));
    #endif

    //Takes in the ammout of indicies not triangels!
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, loader.currentCountOfVerticies);
}
```

code from load shader method

```
glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribPosition, "position");  
glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribNormal, "normal");
glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, "TextCo");
```

Vertex shader

```
//  Created by Jake Cunningham on 13/10/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Jake Cunningham. All rights reserved.
//

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

attribute vec2 TextCo;
varying vec2 textCoOut;

void main()
{
    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

    float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

    colorVarying = diffuseColor * nDotVP;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
    textCoOut = TextCo;
}
```

fragment shader

```
//
//  Created by Jake Cunningham on 13/10/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Jake Cunningham. All rights reserved.
//

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

varying lowp vec2 textCoOut;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = colorVarying * texture2D(texture, textCoOut);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest first testing lighting separate from texturing. The multiply in your fragment shader means that if your texel is black -- which it's likely to be if you're failing to load a texture or have other texturing problems -- you won't see the output of your lighting code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, but I must confess Im still not certain what the problem was. I changed my code from above to

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, total * sizeof(GLfloat), mergedArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Merging both the arrays of vertices and normals into a single buffer resolved the problem. I now have lighting. Why I was unable to use 2 buffers I don't know If any one can spot something I cant I would be grateful for any feed back.

Much thanks to all G.C

Comment: It wasn't the merging of both VBOs into a single one that solved your problem (there is absolutely no problem with different attributes sourced from different buffers), but the merging of both VAOs, like described thoroughly in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your usage of multiple vertex array objects. A vertex array object (VAO) is a lightweight object (meaning it doesn't contain any actual vertex attribute data) encapsulating all the state required for rendering a bunch of vertex arrays with a single draw call, in particular:

- The settings made with `glVertexAttribPointer` for each attribute index
- The enabled attribute arrays
- The bound element array buffer

It is therefore one level higher than the individual vertex attribute arrays, comprising all the vertex attribute array settings of a single (conceptual) scene object, or more correctly, a single draw call.

But in your code you create a new vertex array object for each individual attribute. When then rendering you only bind `_vertexArray` which in turn only sets and enables the `GLKVertexAttribPosition` attribute, thus no normals, or texCoords, or whatever else.

So you should have rather replaced the original code with:

```
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfVerticies * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, arrayOfVerticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

//forget this
//glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_normalArray);
//glBindVertexArrayOES(_normalArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GLKVertexAttribNormal, loader.currentCountOfNormals  * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3,loader.arrayOfNormals , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

//and this, too
//glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_textureArray);
//glBindVertexArrayOES(_textureArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_textureBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfTextureCoordinates * sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, loader.arrayOftextureCoOrdinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```