# Multiple Vertex Buffers OpenGL ES on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I recently solved a problem which prevented my lighting from working in an OpenGL ES iOS app:

[Solved Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103464/open-gl-es-2-0-lighting-not-working-in-ios-app/14113871#14113871)

I solved the problem by replacing

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfVerticies * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, arrayOfVerticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_normalArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_normalArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GLKVertexAttribNormal, loader.currentCountOfNormals  * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3,loader.arrayOfNormals , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

with

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, total * sizeof(GLfloat), mergedArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Combining the array of Vertices and normals to a single `GLfloat` array and passing that array to a single buffer. This resolved my problem, but I don't understand why. To my knowledge I should have been able to use 2 buffers?

Comment: So it seems you don't have an answer to your original question, yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [open GL ES 2.0 lighting not working in iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103464/open-gl-es-2-0-lighting-not-working-in-ios-app)

Comment: For the sake of cleanliness (and even if this means sacrificing the rep I could gain ;)) I would suggest you to delete this question, as I have copied my (supposedly correct) answer over to the original question, which wasn't solved at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem wasn't the usage of multiple vertex buffers, but the usage of multiple vertex array objects. A vertex array object (VAO) is a lightweight object (meaning it doesn't contain any actual vertex attribute data) encapsulating all the state required for rendering a bunch of vertex arrays with a single draw call, in particular

- The settings made with `glVertexAttribPointer` for each attribute index
- The enabled attribute arrays
- The bound element array buffer

It is therefore one level higher than the individual vertex attribute arrays, comprising all the vertex attribute array settings of a single (conceptual) scene object, or more correctly, a single draw call.

But in your original code you create a new vertex array object for each individual attribute. When then rendering you only bind `_vertexArray` which in turn only sets and enables the `GLKVertexAttribPosition` attribute, thus no normals or whatever else.

So you should have rather replaced the original code with:

```
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loader.currentCountOfVerticies * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, arrayOfVerticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

//this is the error
//glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_normalArray);
//glBindVertexArrayOES(_normalArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GLKVertexAttribNormal, loader.currentCountOfNormals  * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3,loader.arrayOfNormals , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```